# BarChart can't be scaled with time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have data I want to display with time, and when I put the scale property in for the line chart like so (as instructed in the documentation for the x-axis)

```
<XAxis 
  dataKey="day" 
  scale="time" 
  type="number" 
  domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} 
  tickFormatter={(t)=> moment.unix(t).format(format)} 
  interval={timeType === 'month' ? 0 : 1} 
/>
```

It works - but when I have this same exact code in my bar chart, the bars won't render?

Is this a bug or is there a reason for why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

There's a work around for this for those of you who come across this issue- you can turn the xAxis dates that you're getting for data into a unix stamp and then sort your data by date and set that equal to your data.

Example:

`resultData = resultData.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time));`